# How to filter out system stopwords in a table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, stop-words

I have a table with English text description in SQL. I want to remove all the stop words in the descriptions by applying full text search. I already used a query to get the table for system stop words and defined full text search on my description table. However, I am still confused as to how to filter out the stop words? Do I need to run a query and how? I have googled a lot but most of the posts only mentioned how to set up the full text search or alter the stop word list. I look forward to getting some advice here.

My steps are below:

1. Created a table: abc.dbo.wc which has only 2 columns:
   ROWID (pk) and Text Description(varchar, around 30 words for each rowid)
2. Use the below query to find system specified stop words in English Language

   SELECT ssw.stopword-- slg.name
     INTO #StopWordsList
     FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords ssw
     JOIN sys.fulltext_languages slg
     ON slg.lcid = ssw.language_id
     WHERE slg.lcid =1033
3. Check if full text search is installed

   `SELECT fulltextserviceproperty('isfulltextinstalled')`  -- 1 is returned
4. Create full text catalogue

   CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG MyFullTextCatalog
5. Create a new full text stoplist from existing system stoplist

   CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST DescriptionStopList
   FROM SYSTEM STOPLIST;

Then I got stuck and don't know how to apply the stoplist to my text column. Eventually I wanna get a table(abc.dbo.wc) without any stop words.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the query you have used along with the table structure and name of the DBMS

Comment: Hey Rohit, code was added. Please let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: It's SQL server

Comment: Do you want to exclude words from #StopWordsList table from results of queries against your full-text catalog OR you want to physically remove words contained in #StopWordList from abc.dbo.wc.TextDescription column? Please, clarify.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I want to physically remove stopwords from the description column if possible. Thanks!